# Enumeration in my python Script is not working as intended?

Tags: python, excel, openpyxl, enumeration

I have been developing a simple enough python script that aims to scrape/copy data out of one excel sheet and place it in another using openpyxl. Everything mostly works except I am getting what I believe is an odd result for a couple of columns.

Basically for some rows, I want to add data that is pulled elsewhere like like file directories etc. So I grab that and store it to a string in a variable and then past the value of that in multiple cells through enumeration. As of right now, this is my code to do that:

```
keyart = str(filedialog.askopenfilename(title="Please select a Keyart file"))
for ws2 in wb2.worksheets:
    if keyart == "":
        break
    else:
        for index, row in enumerate(ws2.rows, start=2):
            ws2.cell(row=index, column=7).value = keyart

vision = str(filedialog.askopenfilename(title="Please select a Video file"))
for ws2 in wb2.worksheets:
    if vision == "":
        break
    else:
        for index, row in enumerate(ws2.rows, start=2):
            ws2.cell(row=index, column=8).value = vision

audio = str(filedialog.askopenfilename(title="Please select a Audio file"))
for ws2 in wb2.worksheets:
    if audio == "":
        break
    else:
        for index, row in enumerate(ws2.rows, start=2):
            ws2.cell(row=index, column=9).value = audio
```

But when I preview the resulting Excel sheet it has pasted "random" amount of values each time in each column giving this staircase effect:

[image: Image of Excel Sheet]

Bascially rows C & D have the correct numbers of rows and the rest don't. What is wrong with my code that it produces this effect and how can I correct it so it enumerates and pasts the values to the correct rows?

Comment: There is no need to use your own counters, just just `ws.iter_rows()` it will save you a lot of hassle.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As an educated guess, there might be an extra row added in the OpenPyxl data model every time you modify the last row. Maybe try getting the number of rows only once? (I cleaned up your for loop to an `if`, assuming you only ever do have one worksheet in the workbook. If that's not the case, you would have to get the number of rows for each worksheet in advance.)

```
ws = list(wb2.worksheets)[0]  # grab a reference to the first worksheet
n_rows = len(ws.rows)  # count the current number of rows

keyart = str(filedialog.askopenfilename(title="Please select a Keyart file"))
if keyart:
    for index in range(2, n_rows):
        ws.cell(row=index, column=7).value = keyart
# repeat for vision with column = 8    
# repeat for audio with column = 9
```